# The installed versions of Studio and Robot do not match. Please restart your machine an try again

Tags: uipath, rpa, uipath-studio, uipath-robot, uipath-orchestrator

I just downloaded UiPath version 21.10.5.0, i installed and when i'm trying to launch it, it's returning an error like **The installed versions of Studio and Robot do not match. Please restart your machine an try again.**

I'm attaching the logs below for your reference

```
11:15:52.1686 => [ERROR] [UiPath.Studio] [4] Error: No license exist for this installation Exception: UiPath.Licensing.Library.Extended.Exceptions.NotLicensedException: No license exist for this installation
   at UiPath.Licensing.Library.Extended.Implementation.OnlineLoader.UpdateAsync(IDictionary`2 userMetadata, ProxySettings proxySettings)
   at UiPath.Licensing.Library.Extended.Implementation.LicenseProvider.UiPath.Licensing.Library.Extended.ILicenseProvider.UpdateOnlineLicenseAsync(IDictionary`2 userMetadata)
11:16:29.1805 => [ERROR] [UiPath.Studio] [5] Acquire orchestrator license error: System.TimeoutException: GetRobotInfoCore timed out.
 ---> System.OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
   at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowOperationCanceledException()
   at System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeClientStream.ConnectInternal(Int32 timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Int32 startTime)
   at System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeClientStream.<>c__DisplayClass20_0.<ConnectAsync>b__0()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<.cctor>b__277_0(Object obj)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(Thread threadPoolThread, ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(Thread threadPoolThread, ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at UiPath.CoreIpc.ServiceClient`1.CheckConnection(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at UiPath.CoreIpc.ServiceClient`1.EnsureConnection(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at UiPath.CoreIpc.ServiceClient`1.<>c__DisplayClass21_1`1.<<Invoke>b__1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at UiPath.CoreIpc.Helpers.Timeout[TResult](TimeSpan timeout, List`1 cancellationTokens, Func`2 func, String message, Func`2 exceptionHandler)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at UiPath.CoreIpc.ServiceClient`1.<>c__DisplayClass21_1`1.<Invoke>b__2(Exception ex)
   at UiPath.CoreIpc.Helpers.Timeout[TResult](TimeSpan timeout, List`1 cancellationTokens, Func`2 func, String message, Func`2 exceptionHandler)
   at UiPath.Studio.Shell.Licensing.LicenseOrchestratorService.AcquireLicensedRobot()
11:16:30.1586 => [ERROR] [UiPath.Studio] [1] RobotVersionChecker try get robot version: System.TimeoutException: GetRobotVersion timed out.
 ---> System.OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
   at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowOperationCanceledException()
   at System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeClientStream.ConnectInternal(Int32 timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Int32 startTime)
   at System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeClientStream.<>c__DisplayClass20_0.<ConnectAsync>b__0()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<.cctor>b__277_0(Object obj)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(Thread threadPoolThread, ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(Thread threadPoolThread, ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at UiPath.CoreIpc.ServiceClient`1.CheckConnection(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at UiPath.CoreIpc.ServiceClient`1.EnsureConnection(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at UiPath.CoreIpc.ServiceClient`1.<>c__DisplayClass21_1`1.<<Invoke>b__1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at UiPath.CoreIpc.Helpers.Timeout[TResult](TimeSpan timeout, List`1 cancellationTokens, Func`2 func, String message, Func`2 exceptionHandler)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at UiPath.CoreIpc.ServiceClient`1.<>c__DisplayClass21_1`1.<Invoke>b__2(Exception ex)
   at UiPath.CoreIpc.Helpers.Timeout[TResult](TimeSpan timeout, List`1 cancellationTokens, Func`2 func, String message, Func`2 exceptionHandler)
   at UiPath.Studio.Shell.App.RobotVersionChecker.Check(), HResult -2146233083
11:16:30.1586 => [WARN] [UiPath.Studio] [1] Incompatible version found Robot: , Studio
```

I'm attaching the image also

[image]

I'm using windows 10 with Nvidia 3070 RTX

Can anyone please let me know how to solve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling the application and re-installing? Seem's a bit odd that the versions of Studio and Assistant are different.

Comment: Yes, it's not working

Answer (score 0):

So the reason for this error is that there is multiple versions between the two applications.

**Option 1**
Uninstall all UiPath Applications.

Go to UiPath Orchestrator > Help > Download.

Make sure you have selected the 'Stable' version

**Option 2**
Restart the Services encase another issue.

Go to Windows services

Find “UiPath Robot” and restart

You can also check out this thread from the UiPath Forum
https://forum.uipath.com/t/open-multiple-project-studio/164352